# Adding map with user location into the profile

Tags: users, location

I am trying to add a *'IPGV&M: Map (Google) centered on visitor's location' block* to all user profiles and I kinda succeeded. The map appears in the user profile, in the footer where i intended to have it, when I visit the user profile it asks if it can use my location. After clicking yes, I face couple problems:

1. It just shows a world's map from far far away without any marker on the location of a user
2. I have to make it so when visiting a user's profile I would be able to see where he/she is from in the map. If I use this method I talked about, doesn't it mean that when I visit someone else's profile I will be still seeing my own location? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but try using the [Location Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/location).  It

> "..allows real-world geographic locations to be associated with Drupal
>   nodes, including people, places, and other content"

God Bless.